# Converting multiple json objects to a single dataframe/csv

Tags: json, dataframe, csv

I'm new with python.

I'd like to know how to run the same process of the code below for multiple urls.

****# Code '1,  that is working perfectly****

```
url ='https://toyama.com.br/wp-json/wp/v2/assistencia?local=914&ramo=&_embed&per_page=100'
header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
df = pd.read_json(url)
resp = requests.get(url, headers=header)
pandas_data_frame1 = df['acf'].apply(pd.Series)
pandas_data_frame1.to_csv ('teste2.CSV', encoding ='utf-8-sig')
```

**# Code2,  that is not working perfectly (multiple urls, it is important to notice that some urls exist and others not, and I need do deal with this structure)**

```
url1 =['https://toyama.com.br/wp-json/wp/v2/assistencia?local=914&ramo=&_embed&per_page=100',
'https://toyama.com.br/wp-json/wp/v2/assistencia?local=800&ramo=&_embed&per_page=100',
'https://toyama.com.br/wp-json/wp/v2/assistencia?local=933&ramo=&_embed&per_page=100',
'https://toyama.com.br/wp-json/wp/v2/assistencia?local=844&ramo=&_embed&per_page=100',
'https://toyama.com.br/wp-json/wp/v2/assistencia?local=806&ramo=&_embed&per_page=100',
'https://toyama.com.br/wp-json/wp/v2/assistencia?local=1207&ramo=&_embed&per_page=100']

header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}

for links in url1:
    df = pd.read_json(links)
    resp1 = requests.get(links, headers=header)
    data = json.loads(resp1.text)
    for d in data:
        pandas_data_frame1 = df['acf'].apply(pd.Series)
        pandas_data_frame1.to_csv ('teste2.CSV', encoding ='utf-8-sig')
```

**#unfortunately only saves the content of the link  'https://toyama.com.br/wp-json/wp/v2/assistencia?local=1207&ramo=&_embed&per_page=100'**

What I need it is to have a csv where I have the json keys as a column, exactly like the code 1.

Kind regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working fine for most of the process. You are loading the data into your workspace and creating a dataframe with the information you need.

Nevertheless, you are replacing the csv file everytime you read a new link information. That is the reason your code is saving just the last link information.

I belive there are many ways to solve it. One simple strategy is to insert a counter to tell the code when just process the information as you did and when join dataframes into a single dataframe.

The code:

```
# Links for scapping web data
url1 =['https://toyama.com.br/wp-json/wp/v2/assistencia?local=914&ramo=&_embed&per_page=100',
'https://toyama.com.br/wp-json/wp/v2/assistencia?local=800&ramo=&_embed&per_page=100',
'https://toyama.com.br/wp-json/wp/v2/assistencia?local=933&ramo=&_embed&per_page=100',
'https://toyama.com.br/wp-json/wp/v2/assistencia?local=844&ramo=&_embed&per_page=100',
'https://toyama.com.br/wp-json/wp/v2/assistencia?local=806&ramo=&_embed&per_page=100',
'https://toyama.com.br/wp-json/wp/v2/assistencia?local=1207&ramo=&_embed&per_page=100']


header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}

# Creating a counter to tell the code when join dataframes.
# For the first case we just create the dataframe. Others case we will join them into a single dataframe.
cont = 0

# Scrapping the Data
for links in url1:
    cont += 1
    
    # Printing which url link the code is reading
    print('loop:' + str(cont))
    
    df = pd.read_json(links)
    resp1 = requests.get(links, headers=header)
    data = json.loads(resp1.text)
    
    
    # First dataframe processing.
    if cont == 1:
        for d in data:
            complete_df = df['acf'].apply(pd.Series)
    
    # Others dataframe processing
    else:
         for d in data:
            others_df = df['acf'].apply(pd.Series)
            complete_df = pd.concat([complete_df, others_df])

# Removing duplciates from the dataframe. I am not sure why but apparently the code is reading few json files.
complete_df = pandas_data_frame1.drop_duplicates()

# Saving CSV file.
complete_df.to_csv ('teste2.CSV', encoding ='utf-8-sig')
```

I hope this may help you.